# My component not updating in realtime when a change happens (react redux project)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I made a shop web application with react-redux
My items in the shop are in a JSON DB, and when I add an item in cart (clicking on buy)  the item goes in another JSON DB.
I have made a component to count items that are in cart. It fetches items from DB and sees how many items are in DB and show a number
But when I click on the buy button the counter doesn't change and need a hard refresh or need to go to another page and back (it used links to route)  to see the new number of the counter.
1. So any idea when usually this happens?  Or what should I do
2.are there a way to update page after clicking on button manually?

Comment: You add an item to a list. The list is still the same list. So component doesn't rerender because the list is not changed.

Comment: @Tien Duong but in my reducer I use (...state), I think it do the job for creating new list

Comment: You create newState. You don't create new list in the state. So the list in the newState is still the old list.

Comment: Actually this is the code in reducer, case FETCH: return{...state, ..._.mapkeys(action.payload,"Id").         By the way are there anyway to update content manually?

Comment: You need to post your UI code in order for us to help you with it.

Comment: create a state for the count and update the count using setState()

Answer (score 0):

1. No change in Display component `assuming a name`, so it is not updating.
2. Call the counter action on click of Buy in  Display component and access the counter in Counter Component from the store `state.counter`.